# C#: Binding hashtable to combo box question

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, hashtable

```
    public class FontType
    {
        ...
        public String Name { get { return _name; } }
        public String DisplayName { get { return _displayName; } }
        public Font UseFont { get { return _font; } }
    }


bindFontTypes.DataSource = availableFonts;
comboFontType.DataSource = bindFontTypes;
comboFontType.ValueMember = "Key";
comboFontType.DisplayMember = ...???;
```

Here, `bindFontTypes` is BindingSource. `availableFonts` is a Hashtable where Keys are strings, and Values are objects of FontType. For `comboFontType.DisplayMember` I want to use objects' .DisplayName property. How do I specify that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if you set

```
comboFontType.DisplayMember = "Value";  // FontType
```

and overload `ToString()` for `FontType`.

As an alternative for ToString() you can handle the Format event of the combobox.

<strike>But I'm not even sure if the databinding works this way.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

By using `DisplayMember = "Value.DisplayName"` I am geting the last one added to the Hashtable...I am working on getting them all....

This is what I did...but only get the last item in the Hashtable to bind....

```
BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
            src.DataSource = new Hashtable 
            { 
            {
                "blah", 
                new FontType 
                { 
                    Name = "newFont", 
                    DisplayName = "new Font" 
                } 
                },
                { 
                    "another", 
                    new FontType 
                    {
                        Name = "anotherFont",
                        DisplayName = "another Font" 
                    } 
                    } 
            };
            comboBox1.DataSource = src;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value.DisplayName";
```

Comment: This gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" somewhere. It's not stand alone program, and it's pain to debug. the other solution worked. But thanks for reply.